# Limiting Parse Query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I would like to retrieve 5 users from Parse, with their latest image posted. But if they haven't posted an image yet, that column will be empty so I have set up my query like this:

```
 func uu() {

let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.includeKey("latestImage")
query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        for object in object! {


            if (object.objectForKey("latestImage") != nil)
            {

                self.lastPicArray.append(object.objectForKey("latestImage")!.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                self.profilePicArray.append(object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                self.fullnameArray.append(object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String)
                self.usernameArr.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)

            }

            }

        self.collectionView.reloadData()


        print(self.usernameArr)
        print(self.lastPicArray)
    }
}
```

}

As you'll see I have added the query.limit = 5 because when I do it seems to get them in some kind of order...And if in that order some users don't have anything in the lastPic column nothing shows...But what I need it to do is find all the users with something in that column and then limit them to 5...At the moment my code is doing all that apart from limiting them to 5!

If anyone knows how do fix this, I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Swift but it is how it will work for you in objective C, you need to incorporate "whereKeyDoesNotExist" in your query and add limit to it. Following is the working code:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"latestImage"];
query.limit = 5;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Got 5 objects");
}];
```

Comment: When I add that it removes all of them...I don't want the key to not exist, I just don't want the empty rows in the column not to exist.

Comment: Yes, it checks for "undefined" values in your Parse class. If for a particular user "latestImage" doesn't exist, it will return those users to you and will limit it to 5 for you.

Comment: I don't want to return the ones where latestImage doesn't exists, the other way round! ;)

Comment: If you want the other way around, you can use "whereKeyExists" in your query. So your query will become like this:
     PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"latestImage"];
query.limit = 5;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Got 5 objects");
}];

Comment: hahaa I did try that but didn't work I got unrecognized identifier, must of typed it wrong! Thanks alot!